# "if 1 & 5" がなぜTrueなのか？

Tags: python

Pythonで`if 1 & 5`とするとTrueが返ってくるのに、`if 2 & 5`とするとTrueが返ってこないのは何故なんですか？考えても答えが見つからなかったので教えて欲しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございます！理解できました！

Comment: ちなみにブール演算の「かつ」は `and` で，`True and False` では `False`,  `2 and 5` では 5, `0 and 5` では 0,  などが返ります（[ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)）．

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。ドキュメント読んでさらに理解できました！

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pythonで　& はビット演算のANDですから、1,2,5を２進数にして考えましょう。
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
5 = 0101

ビット演算のANDなので、両方の数のビットが立っている(1である）桁の結果は１、それ以外は0になります。

1 & 5だと

> ```
> 0001
> ```
>
> & 0101
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 0001
> ```
>
> となります。

また、2 & 5だと

> ```
> 0010
> ```
>
> & 0101
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 0000
> ```
>
> となります。

そして、0がFalseに、0以外がTrueですから、1&5がTrue、2&5がFalseになります。

Comment: 詳しくありがとうございました！

Answer (score 4):

[python](/questions/tagged/python) の演算子 `&` はビット単位の論理積です。
- `1 & 5` の結果は `1` 
- `2 & 5` の結果は `0`
です（これがわからないのなら別途質問してください）。

[python](/questions/tagged/python) の条件式に整数が渡されたとき `0` は偽 `0 以外` は真となり、質問にて書かれたとおりの結果が得られます。

Comment: 「論理和」 : 論理積じゃないですか？

Comment: 読み返していて気づきました。修正します

Answer (score 3):

両辺のビット演算(AND演算)の結果が`0`なら`False`そうでない(0以外)なら`True`と評価されているからと思います。